# Android, onWindowFocusChanged method makes app crash

Tags: android

this is my activity code

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    private String html = "";
    private Handler mHandler;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
        actionBar.setHomeAction(new IntentAction(this, createIntent(this), R.drawable.ic_title_home_default));
        actionBar.setTitle("someTitle");



        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ComposeActivity.class);

        final Action otherAction = new IntentAction(this, intent, R.drawable.ic_title_share_default);
        actionBar.addAction(otherAction);

        mHandler = new Handler();  
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus)
            checkPrice.start();
    }

    public static Intent createIntent(Context context) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        return i;
    }


    private Thread checkPrice = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            actionBar.setProgressBarVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {       
               //...some code
                mHandler.post(showUpdate);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };  

    private Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            actionBar.setProgressBarVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "HTML Code: " + html, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

}
```

After adding the `onWindowFocusChanged` method the Intent `intent`
cannot be started anymore. I get following error:

```
 12-12 10:50:02.468: W/dalvikvm(540): threadid=3: thread exiting with
 uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188) 12-12 10:50:02.468:
 E/AndroidRuntime(540): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to
 uncaught exception 12-12 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):
 java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started. 12-12
 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):   at
 java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1322) 12-12 10:50:02.468:
 E/AndroidRuntime(540):     at
 HomeActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(HomeActivity.java:58)
 12-12 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):     at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:1969)
 12-12 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):     at
 android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3731) 12-12
 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):   at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:657)
12-12 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at
 android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1819) 12-12
 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):   at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-12
 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):   at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 12-12 10:50:02.468:
 E/AndroidRuntime(540):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363) 12-12
 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):   at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-12
 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):   at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 12-12 10:50:02.468:
 E/AndroidRuntime(540):     at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 12-12 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):     at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 12-12
 10:50:02.468: E/AndroidRuntime(540):   at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your onWindowFocusChanged calls `Thread.start()` several times for the same thread which is incorrect. You may want to use a  variable  like `isStarted` to guarantee that `Thread.start()` is called only once. Or start a new thread each time. That depends on your program's logic.

Comment: One way would be new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { /* put your code here */ }}).start(); 
Or it can be your own class implementing Runnable. You define a memeber in your Activity of that class type then pass that member to new Thread.start() each time.

Comment: Preferrable way though to use Executors Java framework or maybe Android AsyncTask. If I explain this here by myself the explanation would be of low quality. Better check the docs about Asynctasks and Executors (that is after you did the required with your Thread).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus && !checkPrice.isAlive())
            checkPrice.start();
    }
```